# обновление Label при нажатии на кнопку python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

При нажатии на кнопку не меняется значение lbl

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('300x250')
tk.title('Clicker')
n = 0

# hook logic
def clicks():
    global n
    n = n + 1
    lbl['text'] = str(n) + '$'

#lbabel
lbl = Label(tk, text = str(n) + '$')

#button
btn = Button(tk, text = 'click me')

#pack
lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: так у вас функция не привязана к кнопке. btn = Button(tk, text = 'click me', commad=clicks) и после изменения по идее нужно label.update

Comment: Благодарю за помощь